# Listing all posts from a certain category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I currently have a **posts model** which has a **category:string** column on it. I'm looking to display all posts in certain categories.

*e.g. On click of 'Technology' category link - load all posts which have apple as the category.*

Couldn't find anything on stack overflow on this, but I may be looking for the wrong thing. Any help would be brilliant and appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your query is `Post.where(category : category_name)` Is this what you want, or you need how to implement the feature you mentioned ?

Comment: Btw you may wan't to create also a category model and have a one-to-many relation between category and post.

Comment: Currently I don't have a category model, I just have a string column which allows me to do     <%= f.select :category, [ 'Tech', 'Animals', 'News'], :prompt => 'Select One' %> Would a category model be better all round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.where(category: 'Animals')`

would return all posts with specified category.

As to comments under the question - yeah, you can benefit from having additional model `Category`, because post can have more, than one category.

You would define the relation as one of the following:

1. HBTM

   `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories # post.rb
   has_and_belongs_to_many :posts # category.rb`
2. has_many through

post.rb

```
has_many :categories_posts
has_many :categories, through: :categories_posts
```

category.rb

```
has_many :categories_posts
has_many :posts, through: :categories_posts
```

categories_posts.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :post
```

**EDIT**

to add selecting category(ies) to form, add the following to it (assuming `Category` has `name` attributes):

```
<%= f.select :categories, Category.pluck(:id, :name), {}, multiple: true %>
```

Also don't forget to whitelist categories in permitted params (`posts_controller.rb`):

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:attr1, :attr2, category_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey - brilliant! How would I go about adding a category with has many, which still allows me to have a similar input as above on the _form.html.erb

Comment: Heh you already added it! How would I go about adding the select input to the view with the new category model?

Comment: Also which solution would you go with #1 or #2? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jonathan I would go with #2 because it has more flexibility (checkout some readings on hbtm vs has_many through). As to form - I'll edit the answer in a minute :)

Comment: Thanks for updating answer - where would I place the desired category names in the view? *noob question*

Comment: @Jonathan if I understand you correctly - you will have to create records - categories. When you have categories in db you can do what I've showed in and you'll get a list of categories names

Comment: ahh so they are static categories which are stored in the category model

Comment: Thanks again for the brilliant answer and help! Much appreciated! Lastly should I set up a DB migration to add the category names to the model?

Comment: @Jonathan, welcome! you can simply open a console and create categories - this would be enough for the case

Comment: Thanks Andrey - you've been awesome! +1

Comment: I fixed the previous code. But now it refuses to save the **category** into the model. Returns this in console **category: nil**. Changed your bit of code to this **<%= f.select :category, Category.pluck(:id, :name), {}, multiple: true %>**.

Comment: you have to be careful with whitelisting params. So you probably will want to double check if you actually allow (permit) the category to be set. Check out strong params

Comment: ah yes - forgot to whitelist :category - my bad! Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm still seems to not be working with :category in the accepted params. **category_ids: [1], :category**.

Comment: Also how would I display the category within the view?

Answer (score 0):

In your post.rb model, add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
scope :animals, -> { where(category: 'Animals') }
```

Then in your controller, you can just call:

```
Post.all.animals
```